# The type arguments for method 'HttpRequest.asJson()' cannot be inferred

Tags: c#, unirest

I am trying to run a C# console program:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Task<HttpResponse<MyClass>> response = Unirest.get("https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/cat/rhymes")
                    .header("X-Mashape-Key", "xxx")
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .asJson();

        }
    }

    internal class MyClass
    {
        public string word { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But this is giving me the following error:

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method 'HttpRequest.asJson()'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.asJson();` needs to know *what type* the json should be deserialized into. In this case, you're using `MyClass`.
Change your code to the following:

```
HttpResponse<MyClass> response = Unirest.get("https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/cat/rhymes")
        .header("X-Mashape-Key", "xxx")
        .header("Accept", "application/json")
        .asJson<MyClass>();
```

Also, you're not calling the async version of `asJson`, so the result type is `HttpResponse<MyClass>`, not `Task<HttpResponse<MyClass>>`.

Please have a read over the examples [here](http://unirest.io/net.html)

Comment: Note that if you use `Dictionary<string, object>`, that's probably the closest to typeless as you can go in this case.